# Can't access the header included in another header?

Tags: c++, header

My have three `.cpp` files and their headers.

```
    //a.cpp
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
void A::foo() {
    C c;
    c.bar();
}


    //a.h
#include "b.h"
class A {
public:
    void foo();
};


    //b.h
#include "c.h"

    //c.h
#pragma once    
class C {
public:
    void bar();
};


    //c.cpp
#include "c.h"
void C::bar() {}

    //other files are ignored
```

But when I compiled them, I got this error:

```
a.cpp:(.text+0xb1): undefined reference to `C::bar()`
```

Have I included `c.h` through `b.h`? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Sorry looks like I forget to clean some old object files. I should run `make clean` first... It's a unqualified question indeed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An undefined reference is a linker error, your code is compiling.  Make sure you are linking `a.obj`, `b.obj` and `c.obj`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a link error, indicating that the definition of `C::bar()` is missing from the set of translation units that are linked to build the program. The most likely reason is that you're not including `c.cpp` in your build.